# I can't use \CurrentOption in commands that are not package specific

Tags: package-writing

I am making a preamble package and I want to give bibfiles as options :

preamble.sty:

```latex
\RequirePackage{biblatex}

\DeclareOption*{
    \addbibresource{\CurrentOption}
    \PackageInfo{preamble}{\CurrentOption added as bibfile}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

main.tex:

```latex
\usepackage[refs.bib]{preamble}
```

When I use `\CurrentOption` inside `\addbibresource`, its content seems to disappear and I get a "BibTeX No data sources defined!" warning. However, I can use it in `\PackageInfo` and "refs.bib added as bibfile" is printed as expected.

For what I understand, `\CurrentOption` can only be used in  package specific command (e.g. `\PackageInfo` or `\PassOptionsToPackage`) and not elsewhere.

Am I right? And if yes, how can I get around this?

Comment: Is this in a `.sty` file?

Comment: Can you show how you call the package.  Passing the bibname as option to the package works fine for me.

Comment: @egreg yes. @Andrew Swann I use the following: `\usepackage[refs.bib]{preamble}`.

Comment: when I put this in a small package and then call `\usepackage[biblatex-examples.bib]{testpack}` it works fine. You should show a complete example.

Comment: Indeed, I made a small complete example and it seems to work, so the problem must come from something else in my package. How can I close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This weird behavior seems to disappear when the `standalone` package is loaded after `\addbibresource`. I've no idea why, but my problem is solved.